# I have this code below i want the counter to reset to 0 after the message is sent

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
let msgCount = 0; // This being outside the event in index.js

// Event here
client.on("messageCreate", async(message)=>{
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.id === "id here") {
        msgCount = msgCount + 1;
    }
    if (msgCount === 100) {
        const channel = await client.channels.cache.get("id here")
       channel.send("hi")  
    }    
})
```

But it only sends the message 1 time and doesn't reset the counter to 0 so it only works 1 time how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You could just wait for the message to be sent and then set the `msgCount`variable to `0`.

```js
let msgCount = 0; // This being outside the event in index.js

// Event here
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.id === "id here") {
        msgCount = msgCount + 1;
    }
    if (msgCount === 100) {
        const channel = await client.channels.cache.get("id here")
        await channel.send("hi")
        msgCount = 0
    }    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reset it... you only increment it. Just use this and it will change it back to `0` when the message is sent

```js
if (msgCount === 100) {
    const channel = await client.channels.cache.get("id here")
    channel.send("hi")
    msgCount = 0
}
```